# Right way to configure listeners property in kafka brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, devops

We have a cluster of 5 brokers and have configured server.properties as below

> listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
>   advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092

I have added entries like below in /etc/hosts file of all the brokers, producers and consumers

> "Private:IP:kafka:broker1" kafka1

This works for us for the most part and we don't have to remember private IPs of the bootstrap servers when configuring new consumers.

I would like to know if this is an okay way to communicate among kafka brokers and clients?

Since I am not a DevOps guy, I am not sure if this could potentially cause hidden problems. Please comment on this.

Another thing is that I am seeing random disconnections among Kafka broker and clients leading to different problems. I just want to clear the possibility that this is somehow causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have added entries like below in /etc/hosts file of all the brokers, producers and consumers

This is **NOT** okay. Please do not do this

If you cannot resolve the hosts via your `bootstrap.servers` property alone, then the listeners are not correct.

Please read [this explanation of Kafka Listeners](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) for all details you could want.

> we don't have to remember private IPs of the bootstrap servers when configuring new consumers

You could use a *service discovery* tool to accommodate for this problem. Consul is a popular one, then you would just point at `kafka.service.consul:9092` and it "just works" via the magic of DNS.

Or you should standardize on a Kafka client library that is already pre-configured with at least the bootstrap servers setting, then you release this "library" internally to your developers for use

Comment: okay. As per the article, it seems that the only problem with hardcoding I.Ps in the local /etc/hosts file is that it's a brittle approach and sort of a hack.
I will change the advertised listeners of all the brokers to their private I.Ps as all our Kafka clients are within the same VPC. 

As far as random disconnections are concerned, I don't think this hack will ever cause the problem as such. or could it?

Comment: Random disconnects could be a timeout exception with clients or Zookeeper latency (as I mentioned previously), or the hardware behind your VPC not able to keep up with replication as well as the client requests e.g. iowait, and cpu load, etc.  But no, the `/etc/hosts` "hack" is only bad when you try to expand the cluster, or you reboot a server in the cloud, and the IP changes

Comment: Thanks, man. I figured that the disconnection issue was because of an existing issue in Kafka itself.  As far as configuring Kafka listeners property is concerned, your ideas look perfect.

Comment: If you feel the issue is within Kafka itself, you're more than welcome to open a JIRA or email the Kafka mailing list for further investigation by the core developers